# Excel Macro to copy select cells from a row from one sheet to another based upon a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do the following with an excel macro.  When a date is entered into a cell on sheet 1 I want to take specific cells from that row and copy them to a new row on sheet 2.  Here is an example.

This would be sheet 1.

```
A         B            C               D            E
proj1     mary         started         -            fiber
proj2     jack         complete        2/7/2014     fiber  
proj3     kim          started         -            cat6
proj2     phil         complete        2/9/2014     fiber
```

Sheet 2 should then look like this since two of them have dates and I only want to bring over specifically the cells from row A,C and D.

```
A         B            C
proj2     complete     2/7/2014
proj2     complete     2/9/2014
```

With the following code I found I'm able to bring over an entire row based on a word value in a cell but not just the specific ones I want and of course I want it to trigger based on a date being entered not the words "reply" or "response".  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Foo()
Dim i As Long, iMatches As Long
Dim aTokens() As String: aTokens = Split("reply,response", ",")
For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("D:D")
    If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then Exit For
        For i = 0 To UBound(aTokens)
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, aTokens(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
                Sheets("sheet1").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("sheet2").Rows(iMatches)
            End If
        Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help. It needs to be placed in the `Worksheet_Change` section.

This assumes your data is in Columns `A:E` in `Sheet1` and you want to copy data over to `Sheet2` once you have entered a date.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nextRow As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        If VBA.IsDate(Target) Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                nextRow = IIf(VBA.IsEmpty(.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)), 1, .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                .Range("A" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, -3)
                .Range("B" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, -1)
                .Range("C" & nextRow) = Target
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alex.  Thank you for the response.  When I try this code it returns only on one line of sheet 2 and not all of the information is there or correct.  Following the example I have above if I change all of them to have a date, sheet2 contains data in row 5 that contains proj3  started   41720  and that's it instead of having all with a data list one after another.

Comment: Alex the new code doesn't seem to change anything.  which ever row I update in sheet1 with a date it always copies over to row 5 of sheet2.    If I add a date to another row in sheet1 it overwrites the contents of row 5 in sheet2.  Thanks!