# Copy Row from one sheet to another if date is entered

Tags: vba, excel

Massive excel noob, have found similar responses and tried to apply it to my own macro but am woefully inadequate in VBA experience/knowledge. Should be an easy fix for you!

I'm basically trying to get data to move from one sheet to another if there is a date in the column T. I want the whole row copied, and then removed from the first sheet (so as to avoid duplicates the next time I click the button. When I run this I get the error "Argument not optional". I understand this to mean I haven't specified a variable somewhere, but I've no idea where that is. Please help!

```
Private Sub Move(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nextRow As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("T:T")) Is Nothing Then
    If VBA.IsDate(Target) Then
        With Worksheets("E+ Resolved")
            nextRow = IIf(VBA.IsEmpty(.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)), 1, .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Range("A" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("B" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("C" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("D" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("E" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("F" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("G" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("H" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("I" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("J" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("K" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("L" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("M" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("N" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("O" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("P" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("Q" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("R" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("S" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("T" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)
            .Range("U" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 0)

        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error "Argument not optional" because whatever is calling your Sub `Move` is not specifying the parameter `Target`.

Search for the place in your code where you're calling your Sub `Move`. If you can reproduce the error, clicking `Debug` in the error dialog should take you to the line of VBA code that contains the error.

Note that you cannot bind the Sub `Move` directly to a button because it is a Sub that takes a parameter. Button click events cannot supply parameters, which is why they can only be bound to Subs with no parameters. If this is what you're trying to do, you should instead create separate Subs that can be bound to buttons such as.

```
Sub Button1Clicked()
    Move Sheet1.Range("A1:Z999")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thanks; I basically copied this code from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662567/excel-macro-to-copy-select-cells-from-a-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-based-upon) and am trying to do the same thing but copy the whole row rather than only certain cells. I don't want lots of buttons for single rows. Is the code I copied doing this automatically? If so, how do I execute the macro?

Comment: The code you copied is specifically for the `Worksheet_Changed` event, which is a reserved function name. If you want this executed whenever a cell is changed, then you have to keep the Sub name `Worksheet_Changed` and place it in the VBA codebehind of the desired sheet(s). You cannot just arbitrarily rename it to `Move` or place the code inside a custom Module.

Comment: Ah right, ok, I understand. Forgive me... this is the first time I am doing a macro, so I have absolutely no idea what goes where or any comprehension of the syntax. So the scenario you described would be ideal... person makes a new entry, fills out the line, then when the date is added ("case resolved"), the macro automatically cuts and pastes the line into the next sheet. I've cut and pasted the code into the sheet 1 back end, and how do I now run it? Changing a date doesn't do anything. The data is in a table, so should I be referencing table 1 or anything? Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: The macro you copied is designed to only copy data when something on column "T" is changed.

Comment: Yes, and this is where the Date field is, however, nothing happens to any rows that have the date entered into column T at this time. What am I missing? Does the rest of the code make sure that data from all the other columns is copied into identical cells?

Comment: The macro will only bee automatically run if it's named `Worksheet_Changed` and if it is located in the codebehind of the sheet that is being modified. You can verify whether it is being run by inserting a breakpoint in the first line of your code. You can then step through the code to determine whether it is performing the actions you expect. If you are unfamiliar with how to use the VBA debugger, please read this: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: I renamed it to Worksheet_Changed, behind the main sheet1, but it has no effect. The more I look at it, the more the code just looks plain wrong. I think the previous code was specific to his problem, and can't be adapted to mine. Isn't there a command like cell.row.copy which needs to be in there?

Comment: No, You can copy the contents of one cell to another simply through assignment. See http://excelexperts.com/copy-values-vba

Comment: Thanks for your help Alain, but its still not getting it. I must be missing something. Step into won't work, I just get a 'ping' and the error 'Argument is not optional' (even with all the changes we've made). Can we start from scratch with the original problem? If there is a date in column T, copy the whole row into sheet 2.